# ReadDirectoryChangesW File Moved Workaround

Tags: winapi, filesystems, filesystemwatcher, readdirectorychangesw

**Background**

Windows API for monitoring file-system changes [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) cannot reliably report a file *move* operation. Instead it just notifies Deleted + Created.

**Question**

What workarounds can be implemented to achieve such a 'Move Event' effect on Windows?
I'm sure I'm not the first one who's dealt with this.

---

My own first thoughts were to save SHA1 sums of everything in the monitored directory (perhaps in a SQLite database) and compare the changed file with the SHA1s, so that if a delete+create happens and their sha1 sums match, we can safely assume it was a move operation. This feels a bit overkill though, I'm wondering if anyone else has already figured out some better workaround.

Any ideas?

Comment: No, it can reliably detect moves.  And reports them with FILE_ACTION_RENAMED* actions.  The typical issue is that there are plenty of programs that don't use move but rewrite the file.  Dealing with them is entirely up to you, there's no one-size-fits-all.

Comment: The question was not about ReadDirectoryChangesW *detecting* moves, but about being reliably *notified* about moves in a manner differentiable from a plain Delete event followed by a plain Create event.

Comment: I could have sworn it said "ReadDirectoryChangesW cannot reliably report a file move operation".  My mistake, good luck.

Comment: If you get create + delete notifications that's because that's what happened. It's not a file move in that case, it's a file create and a file delete. The fact that the data in the old file and the new file was the same is up to you to determine.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Fair enough. The question then is; any suggestions for how to determine that? (Truth is even _then_ you can't be entirely sure it was a move operation... but perhaps that's as good as it gets.)
It's a shame ReadDirectoryChangesW doesn't offer something like Linux 'inotify' IN_MOVED_FROM and IN_MOVED_TO events. I believe file-systems have had atomic move for quite a while now.

Comment: This is what I have observed with my testing in Windows 7:  A MoveFile() call where the src/dst move within the same directory will report as a RENAME event.  A MoveFile() where the src/dst change directories results in a DELETE/CREATE.  This happens if src/target parents are both under the watched folder.  So if the result of the MoveFile() keeps the same parent you get RENAME, otherwise DELETE/CREATE.

Comment: So then the question is also how to detect a move even when parent folder changes (all within a watched tree of course)

Comment: When moving a directory a to b\a, ou get exactly a: Deleted 'a', Created 'b\a', Update 'b'. It's definitly a wierd combinaison. I'm trying to create a sync tool and this is a really bad case.